# Realm - Second insert with throws error: Error: 'xxx' must be of type 'string', got 'null' (null)

Tags: react-native, realm

Upgrading to `Realm 10.8.0` in a `React-Native` project when I perform an insert/write to a schema the first one is successful, but the second insert throws the following error: `Error: Workflows.InternalName must be of type 'string', got 'null' (null)`

I cannot determine why the first insert was successful and the second errors?  This is a sandbox text where the value are hard-coded and definitely not `null`.

**package.json**

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.65.1",    
"realm": "^10.8.0"
```

**App.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { View, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    import Realm from 'realm';

    class Workflows {
        ExternalName;
        InternalName;

        static schema = {
            name: 'Workflows',
            primaryKey: 'InternalName',
            properties: {
                ExternalName: 'string',
                InternalName: 'string',
            }
        };
    }

    export default class App extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.realm = new Realm({
                schema: [Workflows],
                schemaVersion: 1,
            });
            console.log("Db: Realm created");
        }

        record;
        ctr = 0;

        saveData = () => {
            let workflows = new Workflows();
            workflows.InternalName = "Internal Name" + this.ctr;
            workflows.ExternalName = "External Name" + this.ctr;
            this.ctr++
            try {
                this.realm.write(() => {
                    this.record = this.realm.create(Workflows.schema.name, workflows);
                })
                this.record = this.realm.objects(Workflows.schema.name);
                console.log(`The lists of workflows are: ${this.record.map((workflow) => workflow.InternalName)}`);
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <View style={styles.appContainer} >
                    <Button title="Save Realm data" onPress={this.saveData} />                      
                </View>
            );
        }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        appContainer: {
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
        }
    })
```

The following test have different results.

1. Adding logging after the `new Workflows()` and subsequent assignment shows the second `workflows` object does not get created properly (but ONLY if the `realm.create` is in the code)

   ```
    let workflows = new Workflows();
    workflows.InternalName = "Internal Name" + this.ctr;
    workflows.ExternalName = "External Name" + this.ctr;
    console.log("workflows InternalName: " + workflows.InternalName)
    console.log("workflows ExternalName: " + workflows.ExternalName)
    console.log("workflows object: ", workflows)

    *CONSOLE OUTPUT*
    LOG  Running "Test" with {"rootTag":171}
    LOG  Db: Realm created
    LOG  workflows InternalName: Internal Name0
    LOG  workflows ExternalName: External Name0
    LOG  workflows object:  {"ExternalName": "External Name0", "InternalName": "Internal Name0"}
    LOG  The lists of workflows are: Internal Name0
    LOG  workflows InternalName: null
    LOG  workflows ExternalName: null
    LOG  workflows object:  {}
    LOG  [Error: Workflows.InternalName must be of type 'string', got 'null' (null)]
   ```
2. Using the following `realm.create` works everytime (vs passing an object variable):
   `this.realm.create(Workflows.schema.name, { InternalName: "Internal Name" + this.ctr, ExternalName: "External Name" + this.ctr });`
3. Commenting out the `this.realm.create(Workflows.schema.name, workflows);` caused the object to be created and assigned correctly, but obviously now to write/insert is performed.

Comment: Please ensure you include debugging details in your question and that you're stepped through your code line by line inspecting your vars along they until something doesn't look right. This `+ this.ctr;` is suspect but we really need to know what's you've done to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Jay - The second time I press the button and `new` up a second instance of `Workflow` the properties never get assigned or are not there, they remain null (not undefined).  Also if I run this same program in react-native debug it works fine.  Additionally if I hard code and object to pass to the save it works, Example: `this.realm.create(Workflows.schema.name, { InternalName: "Internal Name" + this.ctr, ExternalName: "External Name" + this.ctr });`  I am very baffled why this is occurring.  If I comment out the realm.create statement and do not save the object is created as expected.

Comment: I will update above with what I have tried and the results, I didnt include it at first because I wanted a short concise post.